# In App Billing service getting killed at times

Tags: android, service, in-app-billing, termination

Hi we released this app in the market with inApp Billing and our logs show that the BillingService(possibly the app itself) keeps getings killed very randomly on certain customers devices. Because of this sometimes I am not able to get the notification if the purchase was successful or not. Some of the customers often have to buy twice to make a successful purchase. Though this happens to a small percentage of customers but it is very troubling. Any idea why it might be happening or what can be done to work around this problem.

Comment: Whereabouts in the process is it getting killed?  It typically goes from Android Market broadcast notification -> Your BillingReceiver onReceived() -> BillingReceiver sends purchased intent to BillingService -> BillingService handles and updates purchased info.

Comment: The thing is its pretty random and I am yet to repro this issue on my device. It happens to a small percentage of users, but I would want to fix it anyways.

Comment: The randomness does make it much harder :)  Are you able to add more tracking info in the app? Acra is a error tracking tool I find useful.  Also, it could also be aggressive Task Killer apps.

Comment: ACRA is indeed there in the app but it too fails to report anything

Comment: @the100rabh did your problem solve?

Comment: Nope, problem did not get solved, till Google released the new version of PlayStore App.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure whether it will help, but I would recommend to make your BillingService foreground service: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html#Foreground

Here is piece of documentation
"API to put the service in a foreground state, where the system considers it to be something the user is actively aware of and thus not a candidate for killing when low on memory. "

It could be that small percentage of your user has low memory condition and it's start killing services/applications (including yours).

Comment: Yeah, ur right about low memory. Thats my guess too but. But making it a foreground process is a good suggestion indeed. This might help. But the fact is the entire process seems to restart, not just the service.

Comment: In the case if you have no foreground activities (or services) at that moment, system may (and most probably will) kill the whole process in the low memory condition.

Answer (score 0):

Can you put up the code used for your in app billing? It could be that In app billing isn't supported by their devices or even if they lose internet connection when trying to access the Android Market broadcast notification. What I used in my app is basically like this :

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
if( BillingHelper.isBillingSupported()){
        switch (arg2) {
        case 0:         
            Log.d("Appname", "30 coins");
            BillingHelper.requestPurchase(context, "com.paid.smallcoinbundle"); 
                 break;
        case 1: 
            Log.d("Appname", "85 coins");
            BillingHelper.requestPurchase(context, "com.paid.medcoinbundle"); 
                 break;
        case 2: 
            Log.d("Appname", "175 coins");
            BillingHelper.requestPurchase(context, "com.paid.midcoinbundle"); 
                 break;
        case 3:  
            Log.d("Appname", "500 coins");
            BillingHelper.requestPurchase(context, "com.paid.maxcoinbundle"); 
                 break;
        default: Log.d("Appname", "Something broke");
        break;
        }
    //  BillingHelper.requestPurchase(mContext, "android.test.purchased"); 
        // android.test.purchased or android.test.canceled or android.test.refunded or com.blundell.item.passport
    } else {
        LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
        View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.toast_layout,(ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.toast_layout_root));
        TextView text = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.text);
        text.setText("In App Billing isnt supported by your device");
        Toast toast = new Toast(getBaseContext());
        toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL, 0, 0);
        toast.setDuration(Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        toast.setView(layout);
        toast.show();
        return;
    }
}
```

Then :

```
public Handler mTransactionHandler = new Handler(){
    public void handleMessage(android.os.Message msg) {
        Log.d("Appname", "Transaction complete");
        Log.d("Appname", "Transaction status: "+BillingHelper.latestPurchase.purchaseState);
        Log.d("Appname", "Item purchased is: "+BillingHelper.latestPurchase.productId);

        if(BillingHelper.latestPurchase.isPurchased()){
            Log.d("Appname", "Ispurchased : " + BillingHelper.latestPurchase.productId);
            if(BillingHelper.latestPurchase.productId.equals("com.paid.smallcoinbundle")){
                ConnectToServer.UpdateCoins(context,id,"add","30");
            }
            if(BillingHelper.latestPurchase.productId.equals("com.paid.medcoinbundle")){
                ConnectToServer.UpdateCoins(context,id,"add","85");
            }
            if(BillingHelper.latestPurchase.productId.equals("com..paid.midcoinbundle")){
                ConnectToServer.UpdateCoins(context,id,"add","175");
            }
            if(BillingHelper.latestPurchase.productId.equals("com.paid.maxcoinbundle")){
                ConnectToServer.UpdateCoins(context,id,"add","500");
            }

            finish();
        }
    };
```

};

Since you said that in app billing does work, although sometimes they need to purchase the item twice, I assume that your package names are correct.

Please let me know if you go about fixing it and what the problem was. This is a very interesting topic.

Comment: This is indeed interesting, the code is kind of picked directly from Google sample code. It works perfectly fine for most users. A handful of them experience this issue.

Comment: In that case it would probably be a bug with the system. Write up a bug report to the Dev team. I'm sorry that I could not help you.

Comment: Hi Randy, Thanks for trying to help me :)